# Squid3 to use a parent SSH SOCKS proxy?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, squid

I would like to have a local squid3 server to use the forwarded parent SOCKS port 9999, and serve local users at local server port 3128 to avoid govt censorship...

I have SSH tunnel forwarding a remote SOCKS port to local:

```
SSH -D 9999 remote_user@remotehost
```

To illustrate the problem

```
 LOCAL USERS       LOCAL SERVER                  REMOTE SERVER
                   ++++++++++++                  +++++++++++++ 
                   +   ???    +     SSH TUNNEL   +           +
^_^ ^_^ ^_^ --> 3128  squid3  9999   ------->   22  sshd  ----> INTERNET
                   +          +                  +           +
                   ++++++++++++                  +++++++++++++
```

I know the basics of setting squid3 and make it working, but not sure how to set the conf in squid3 to use the SOCKS5 parent??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a good alternative to squid, polipo supports this feature!